# Emoticon of a globe want displayed in the output - Java

Tags: java, javafx

So I a have a program that runs a headline news

I want to add a globe before and after each text

this is what I get instead. A box instead of a globe. Am I missing something
[image]

this is my code

```
String messageBody = " " + "\uD83C\uDF0D" + " " 
                 + latestMessage.text + " " + "\uD83C\uDF0D" + " ";
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: what GUI toolkit are you using, Swing?

Comment: @kennytm javaFX

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f310/index.htm).

Try replacing the text with this

`&#127760;`

Comment: so you mean it becomes like this?

Comment: `String messageBody = " " + &#127760 + " " 
                 + latestMessage.text + " " + &#127760 + " ";`?

Comment: It's not a html/xml question, but a java question and the problem is probably caused by the font not containing a symbol for the letter the op tries to use...